# C# how to serialize binary incremental data

Tags: c#, serialization, binary

I'm developing a piece of acquisition software (in C#) where the acquired data must be stored on the harddrive as they arrive (storing in chunks is acceptable and preferable).

I've chosen for a serializable object with more or less the following structure:

```
[Serializable]
public class MyData
{
    public string LocationId;

    public DateTime TimeStamp;

    public List<float[]> MyData;
}
```

If I use the binary formatter for serialization as follows:

```
public void Serialize(string filename)
{
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create);

    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    try
    {
        formatter.Serialize(fs, this);
    }
    catch (SerializationException)
    {
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        fs.Close();
    }
}
```

it works, but the serialization will happen once the acquisition is complete and before it the complete data resides in memory as `MyData`.

What I want to achieve is that:

- when I start the acquisition, only the "fixed" fields (i.e. `LocationId` and `TimeStamp`) are written to file
- once the `MyData` achieves the count of, say, 100, it gets appended to the file
- after appending the file with the data, the `MyData` gets cleared
- every time another, say, 100 list items are added, they are appended to the file and `MyData` gets cleared
- deserialization will never happen while the data is acquired, it is thus not an issue to handle the data while it is growing (and quite often it will take place on a separate, much powerful, hardware)

why's:

- I want the result file to be binary and not JSON, XML or YAML because there is a lot of data acquired and I don't want to bloat the file
- I want the file to be periodically appended because I don't want to keep all the appended data in memory (again, data amount) and should something go wrong, I can live with having last chunk lost but not all the data
- I want to periodically dump the data to file because hard drive capacity is usually (at least in the hardware we are planning to use) much larger than available RAM (where the `MyData` is stored)

I've searched SO already for similar issues and I can't find any that would suggest any solution except of writing my own serializer.

Should I write my own serializer, I was thinking of:

- storing the "fixed" fields in a form of YAML or JSON
- appending the binary data after some marker
- keeping the order of the file as "fixed" fields first, data always at the end

Such a solution would allow some VTS (version tolerant serialization) within the "fixed" fields area while not bloating the file size. The format of the data is standardised and in fact determined by the external hardware but defining the list item structure in the header ("fixed") fields is also an option.

I don't want to reinvent the wheel, hence my question whether you know an existing solution to my issue.
And if not, is my own serializer approach complete or did I miss some aspects?

Comment: _"If I use the binary formatter"_ - No, don't. Please don't. [Warning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter?view=net-5.0#remarks) : _"BinaryFormatter is insecure and can't be made secure. For more information, see the BinaryFormatter security guide."_

Comment: I'm aware of that. Hence my question.

Comment: What's the expected size of such a file? And for the timestamp: do you care for localization? You may consider DateTimeOffset ...

Comment: In practice it will be something between 100 and 500 MB, but the requirement is to have it limited by the available hard drive space only. Thank you for the tip on timestamp.

Comment: I think, I'd make that actually two files: a "Header" File and a "Data" File. Into the Header file go timestamp and locationId (whatever you like, XML, Yaml, JSON ...). And the Datafile can be appended to unrelated to the first one. Later on, I'd probably zip them up to create my own "Container File Format".

Comment: Seems reasonable. It's kind of similar approach to what I had in mind with my own serializer. I get the feeling that more people were reinventing the wheel in this aspect.

Comment: Well, the "streaming" part is not _that_ common. If it wasn't for that, I would have suggested something like "sqlite as an application file format" ... but with that special requirement... meh.

Comment: I also used to work in a field that had similar requirements, but I cannot talk about that (still under NDA). Out of that expierience, you may want to even consider more "chunk" files. But that will then require another file to coordinate order etc ... (which could be the Header file).

Comment: I get it, say no more ;) Thank you, I know which direction I should go with my development now.